# Problem with the output self implemented “ Iterative FFT DIT Radix2 ” algorithm matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-spectrum, math, simulink

I´m trying to implement my own FFT with the iterative Radix2 algorithm (I even thought about using the recursive one but it seems Simulink doesn´t allow me to). I tried all of the possible variations of it, like DIT and DIF, but I always get the same result and the output doesn´t make much sense to me.

Being then used for a Welch Estimation, the signal will be buffered and those data packages are then windowed and overlapped. The window function will be then averaged and sent to the next block in Simulink in order to get a Welch Spectral estimation.

Here is my code for (one of) the DIT version I implemented:

```
function FFT = FFT(u,k_old,lap)
% where u is the buffered signal, k_old is the iteration number (starting from 
% 0 for the first loop) and lap = N/2 (50% overlap)

N = length(u);
P = log2(N);
FFT = zeros(N,1)+0*1j;
omega = 0j;

% Hann Window
n1 = (k_old)*lap:(N+k_old*lap-1);
w1 = sin(pi.*n1/(N-1)).^2;
z1 = u.*w1';
z1=z1';

% Average
Wk = 0;
for i=1:N
    Wk = Wk + w1(i)^2;
end

%% Algorithm
A = z1(bitrevorder(1:N));
for s=1:log2(N)
    m=2^s;
    Wm = exp(2*pi*1j/m)
    W = 1 +0j;
    for j= 1:m/2
        for k=j:m:(N)
            odd = W*A(k+m/2)
            even = A(k);
            FFT(k)=odd + even;
            FFT(k+m/2) =even-odd;
        end
        W = W*Wm;
    end
end
```

The input is a sine wave and instead of the two expected spikes this is what I get (even if I switch the noise off or the window function the result doesn´t change):

[image]

Why does it look like that?
I first thought it was a frequency normalization Problem but, it didn´t solve it.

I really hope anyone can help and that the question isn´t too banal, I´m completely lost!

Comment: Your code is incomplete. N is not defined. k_old is not defined, etc.

Comment: sorry it got cut off in the editing. I repair it right now :)

Comment: Start simple, try a two-point and see what you get. Another option is to input a single one (the rest zeros) and see what result you get. I'd do that without the Hann window etc. Make one thing work and so on.

Comment: I tried a two point implementation (so not iterative) and it works perfectly. The problem is that the complexity drops down to around O((N/2)^2), still too heavy for a meaningful comparison. The single one input may be a good idea thou! Also the window function works perfectly, I tried with it off and to keep it as simple as I could. Unluckily no different result. What makes me think is that DIT and DIF both written in slightly different forms, give me the same result (the one posted). So I was wondering it may depend on a different interpretation of the output or something completely missing.